# Can I store txt files in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Hi is it possible to store .txt files inside azure sql database? if not then which service provides this?

Comment: Do you want save the txt file data to Azure SQL database table column?

Answer (score 1):

You can write them into an nvarchar(max) column if you'd like.  If they are CSV files, you may want to shred them into columns in a table.  However, if you have a lot of text file data, you may find it cheaper to use Azure Storage instead.  It is generally better for colder data where you don't need to process it if your text data is all want to store or if it is a majority of what you are trying to store.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can have them first uploaded/stored on an [Azure Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/) and have them automatically processed and uploaded to a table on an Azure SQL Database using Azure Functions as explained [here](https://github.com/yorek/AzureFunctionUploadToSQL). Azure Functions have triggers to respond to an event like a new file has been uploaded.